# Nuxt .env and import a js into a store

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a somewhat large config.js file that I have created to for config type things. I am using a .env to keep secrets and such out of my github. In my .env file I have a variable called environment that I use to determine if I am on local, dev, stage, or prod. In my config.js file I am using that to load my certs and keys, and a bunch of other variables that are dependent on which environment I am on.

In one of my Vuex Store files, when I do the following it works

```
import config from '@/config'  
console.log(process.env.enviorment) // This logs out 'development' which i set in my .env file
const environ = config.developmemt
```

When I do the following I get 'environ is undefiend', even though I can see 'development' logged out.

```
import config from '@/config'  
console.log(process.env.enviorment) // This logs out 'development' which i set in my .env file
const environ = config[process.env.enviorment]
```

My VueEx file...

```
import config from '@/config'
console.log(process.env.enviorment) // <--- This is where it loads undefined at the app.js file which is my store, but loads the value in client.js
console.log(this.app) // <----------- this.app is undefined every time.
const environ = config.developmemt


export const state = () => (
{
 environment: eviron
}
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use .env variables in Nuxt 2 or 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703133/how-to-use-env-variables-in-nuxt-2-or-3)

Comment: Nuxt 2, and no. Each of those describe everything but the Vuex store. From what I can tell the Store is getting loaded before the .env file gets loaded. As what I am seeing is the app.js store is showing the console as undefined, but then client.js is loading the data just fine.

Comment: How about this one so? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553464/8816585 Also, env variables are loaded first to my knowledge.

Comment: this.app is undefined

Comment: Please share the exact snippet of code where this is undefined.

Comment: I've edited the post to include my full Vuex file.

Comment: If you want to have some state set from the start, you also can use [`nuxtServerInit`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action). Because my previous answer is related to having the state into a **vuex action**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use process.env only during build process. You want to use ENVs in **runtime**. In nuxt we have built-in ENVs handling:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config#runtimeconfig

In **.env** file add your ENVs:

```
ENVIRONMENT=staging
```

In **nuxt.config.js** you can use process.env.ENVIRONMENT, because it will be assigned during build time:

```
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    environment: process.env.ENVIRONMENT
  },
};
```

Then you can get all your ENVs from publicRuntimeConfig during runtime (in vue and store files):

```
this.$config.environment
```

You can check my demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-envs-hx2cw?file=/pages/index.vue

Comment: Actually, we do actually have a `isDev` property in the context too: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers

Comment: I should have clarified, this is exactly what I did, I just did not use this.$config, instead using process.env. However now that I am trying this.$config I am getting "Cannot read property '$config' of undefined."  In my Vuex store above the only line I changed was console.log(process.env.enviorment) to be console.log(this.$config)

Comment: @Jamie probably it's because you are trying this.$config outside mutation/action and you don't get this context.
Check again, I added comments:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-envs-hx2cw?file=/store/index.js

You can also check if you can get this.$config in any .vue file.

Comment: @kissu That's true, but sometimes isDev is not enough. For example you may want to add some libraries (e.g. analytics) only in production but not staging. Both production and staging has 'isDev === false', but still you don't know if it's staging or production.

Comment: True! This one is still valid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840426/nuxt-env-and-import-a-js-into-a-store/69846526?noredirect=1#comment123473512_69840426

Comment: @Cianekjr is config available at the state level in the store? When I try it using your code except just use the heading: this.$config.environment in the state rather than the mutation, I get $config unavailable. I think the answer is no, but want to confirm. It just means Ill have to refactor some of the code a bit more than I thought.

Comment: @Jamie I think so. Probably there is not way to get "this" content at the state level.

Comment: Yep, as I've linked you before: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7602#issuecomment-735385911