can not access variables from process.env in nuxt 2 in nuxt.config.js
I created a process.env file in order to store a data to make api calls. I tried to define variables in my nuxt.config.js to use them in my vuex store but in config file I cant access them. Here is my code:
it's my nuxt.config:
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
   target: 'static',

   publicRuntimeConfig: {
   clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID || 'hi',
   clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
  },
 }

store.js:
const actions = {

async fetchData(context) {
    const clientId = this.$config;
    console.log(clientId);
    try {
        const apiEndpoint = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/';
        const response = await this.$axios.get(`curl -H "Authorization: Basic {BASE64_ENCODED(${this.$config.clientId}:${this.$config.clientSecret})}" ${apiEndpoint}`)

        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
    
    } finally {
    
    }
    
},}

console.log(clientId) returns hi

Does this one maybe help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553464/8816585
